# C# Rewrite ODT Links and download associated files

Tags: c#, .net

I have a problem for several weeks on my c# code, my application is used to read an ODT file and download all the documents (pointed by links in this file). The problem is that when I run my program, I have the right number of files that are downloaded and the number of links present in the document, but the downloaded files are not PDFs but are 18kb files with the code inside the code of an identification page. I can't retrieve and store the authentication cookie to allow it to be used for downloads

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Core;
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip;

namespace PrepareDocForExternalUse
{
    class Program
    {
        private static CookieContainer Login(string username, string password)
        {
            string uriString = "https://applnet.test.fr/CASServer/login.aspx?";
            CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            string postData = "username=" + username + "&password=" + password;
            byte[] postDataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uriString);
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            httpWebRequest.ContentLength = postDataBytes.Length;
            httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;

            Stream requestStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(postDataBytes, 0, postDataBytes.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            CookieCollection cookies = httpWebResponse.Cookies;

            return cookieContainer;
        }

        /* private static string ReadPassword()
        {
            string password = "";
            ConsoleKeyInfo key;

            do
            {
                key = Console.ReadKey(true);

                if (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter && key.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape)
                {
                    if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && password.Length > 0)
                    {
                        password = password.Remove(password.Length - 1);
                        Console.Write("\b \b");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        password += key.KeyChar;
                        Console.Write("*");
                    }
                }

            } while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter && key.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);

            Console.WriteLine();

            return password;
        } */

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string username = "";
            string password = "";
            /* Console.WriteLine("Veuillez saisir votre mot de passe:");
            string password = ReadPassword();*/
            CookieContainer cookieContainer = Login(username, password);

            // Demande à l'utilisateur le chemin absolu d'un fichier ODT
            Console.WriteLine("Merci de renseigner le chemin absolu d'un fichier ODT:");
            string odtFilePath = Console.ReadLine();


            // Lis le contenu du fichier ODT
            byte[] content = File.ReadAllBytes(odtFilePath);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            ms.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
            ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(ms);
            zf.UseZip64 = UseZip64.Off;
            zf.IsStreamOwner = false;
            ZipEntry entry = zf.GetEntry("content.xml");
            Stream s = zf.GetInputStream(entry);

            // Convertit le stream en string
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(s);
            string contentXml = reader.ReadToEnd();

            // Recherche tous les liens qui commencent par "applnet.test.fr"
            string pattern = @"http://applnet\.test\.fr/GetContenu/Download\.aspx\?p1=.*?;p2=.*?;p5=.*?;p6=NOPUB";
            Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
            MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(contentXml);


            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(odtFilePath));

            // Traite chaque lien trouvé
            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                string link = match.Value;
                string[] parts = link.Split(new string[] { "aspx?" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                string queryString = parts[parts.Length - 1];



                // Télécharge le document intranet correspondant
                string folderName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(odtFilePath);
                string subFolderName = "PJ - " + folderName;
                string fileName = queryString;
                string localFilePath = "C:/PiecesJointes/" + fileName;
                string onlineFilePath = "https://com.test.fr/files/test/banque/" + queryString;

               


                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(link);
                request.Timeout = 30000;
                request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
                request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                request.Method = "GET";
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                int bytesRead = 0;
                FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(localFilePath, FileMode.Create);

                do
                {
                    bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                } while (bytesRead > 0);


                fileStream.Close();
                response.Close();


                // Remplace le lien par le chemin du document téléchargé
                string newLink = localFilePath.Replace("\\", "/");
                contentXml = contentXml.Replace(link, onlineFilePath);
            }

            // Met à jour le content.xml dans le fichier ZIP initial
            byte[] contentXmlBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(contentXml);
            ms = new MemoryStream();
            zf.BeginUpdate();



            // Ajoute le contenu mis à jour au fichier ZIP
            ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(ms);
            zos.UseZip64 = UseZip64.Off;
            zos.IsStreamOwner = false;

            // Ajoute l'entrée pour le fichier content.xml
            zos.PutNextEntry(new ZipEntry(entry.Name));
            StreamUtils.Copy(new MemoryStream(contentXmlBytes), zos, new byte[4096]);


            // Traite chaque entrée du fichier ODT original
            foreach (ZipEntry origEntry in zf)
            {
                // Ignore l'entrée pour le fichier content.xml car il a déjà été ajouté
                if (origEntry.Name == entry.Name) continue;

                // Ajoute l'entrée au nouveau fichier ZIP
                zos.PutNextEntry(new ZipEntry(origEntry.Name));
                StreamUtils.Copy(zf.GetInputStream(origEntry), zos, new byte[4096]);
            }

            zos.Close();

            // Termine la mise à jour du fichier ZIP
            zf.CommitUpdate();
            zf.Close();


            // Renomme et enregistre le fichier ODT mis à jour
            Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
            string updatedFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(odtFilePath), g + "_" + Path.GetFileName(odtFilePath));
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(updatedFilePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                ms.Position = 0;
                ms.WriteTo(stream);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Le fichier ODT a été mis à jour avec succès et enregistré sous le nom : " + updatedFilePath);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

I tried to retrieve the session cookie but my variable is empty

Comment: the problem is that it's an intranet, so you can't access on this website